# How to copy multiple values in Excel to other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in aa1:aa10.
I also have data in ab1:ab10
I also have data in ac1:ac10 
etc all the way to aj1:aj10.

i would like to place aa1 in a1, ab1 in a2, ac1 in a3 all the way to aj1 in a10.
i would like to place aa2 in a11, ab2 in a12, ac1 in a13 all the way to aj2 in a20.
etc all the way to aa10 in a101, ab10 in a102, ac10 in a103 all the way to aj10 in a110.

I need to be able to replicate the formula whilst skipping values. at the moment when i drag a1 down to a11, a11 becomes the value of aa11 rather than aa2.

Hope this problem is solvable

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do. Also, it looks like you reused the same rows, unless you want the data in ab1:ab10 to overwrite the data in aa1:aa10.

Comment: This will work for your `AA1:AA10` into `D1, D11, D21, D31....D91` but breaks after that.  It ignores that you want `D11, D21, D31` to also show the values from `AB1:AB10` as that needs clarifying.  `=IF(ROW()=CEILING(ROW()-10,10)+1,INDIRECT("AA" & SUM(LEFT(ROW(),1),IF(LEN(ROW())>1,RIGHT(ROW(),1),0))),"")` - just add to cell D1 and drag down.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want is converting a 2D matrix into a single column vector, taking the elements rowwise.

Take a look here, they explain pretty well how to do it.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2775-excel-convert-matrix-to-single-column.html